# How to find value below a specific cell in another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a sheet containing color names on several rows with associated numbers in the row directly below them.

In a separate sheet, I want to use a formula to return the color values in a column next to the color names

### Sample Data

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | red | blue | green | yellow |
| **2** | 10 | 10 | 0 | 500 |
| **3** | blue | yellow |  |  |
| **4** | 10 | 500 |  |  |
| **5** | blue | green |  |  |
| **6** | 10 | 0 |  |  |
| **7** | red | green |  |  |
| **8** | 10 | 0 |  |  |

### Sample Results

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | red | 10 |
| **2** | blue | 10 |
| **3** | blue | 10 |
| **4** | red | 10 |
| **5** | blue | 10 |
| **6** | yellow | 500 |
| **7** | green | 0 |
| **8** | green | 0 |
| **9** | green | 0 |
| **10** | yellow | 500 |

**Data in Sheet1**
[image: sheet 11]

**List of Colors in Sheet2**
[image: sheet 2]

Comment: Dario, it would be helpful if you [edit] your question to clarify why there are duplicate combinations in the original data and in the results sheet there are also duplicate colors however there isn't a one-to-one relationship and it isn't clear what the order of numbers is.  Will a specific color always have the same value?  Do you want to list the duplicates?  Are you trying to get a count? etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
=WRAPROWS(TOCOL(A:D,1,1),2)
```

1. [TOCOL](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13187258) stacks the range into a single column:

   - `ignore` is set to `1` to skip blanks
   - `scan_by_column` is set to `TRUE` or `1`
2. [WRAPROWS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13184285) converts the column into 2 column rows by setting the `wrap_count` to `2`.

Answer (score 0):

To get the lowest number under each unique text label above such number, use `query()` and `filter()`, like this:

```
=lambda( 
  data, 
  lambda( 
    colors, numbers, 
    query( 
      { colors, numbers }, 
      "select Col1, min(Col2) 
       group by Col1 
       label min(Col2) '' ", 0 
    ) 
  )( 
    filter(data, istext(data)), 
    filter(data, isnumber(data)) 
  )  
)( 
  { 
    filter( 
      flatten(transpose(A1:D100)), 
      len(flatten(transpose(A1:D100))) 
    ) 
  } 
)
```

If you are looking for a way to find numbers by their cell fill color, that cannot be done with a formula that uses Google Sheets built-in functions, because none of those functions has access to cell formatting such as fill colors. If that is what you need, you will have to use a [script](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info), or devise another way to categorize your data that does not depend on fill colors.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - Let's get that array of original data into a single column. Since you didn't share the spreadsheet, I made my own with the data in a tab called "Data". All three formulas go in a separate tab ("Solution" in my spreadsheet)

```
=FILTER({Data!A:A;Data!B:B;Data!C:C}, LEN({Data!A:A;Data!B:B;Data!C:C}))
```

Step 2 - Pull out the colors into their own column: (This filter will show only the even numbered rows)

```
=FILTER(A1:A, MOD(ROW(A1:A), 2) = 0)
```

Step 3 - Pull out the values under the colors in the adjacent column: (This filter will show only the odd numbered rows)

```
=FILTER(A1:A, MOD(ROW(A1:A), 2) = 1)
```

You may need to swap the even and odd filters depending on if you have a header row. You could make the first step simpler, but I don't know if you happen to have a ragged array. This formula will work even if you do. Here's my spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ocbmzv9WCJYpE30bjL7ZQ32C5aj4ve-UD32XW6tGZCs/edit?usp=sharing